# How To Load classes using ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader

I have an interface named Operator the directory of this interface is d:\operators
Interface definition is like so :

```
package operators;

public interface Operator
{
    double calculate(double firstNumber,double secondNumber);
    String getSign();
}
```

In the main program (d:\ProjectFile94.6.7\main) I want load this interface and use it  .I load interface like so  :

```
String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator");
            String operatorsPath = rootPath.replace("ProjectFile94.6.7" , "").replace("main" , "") + "operators";
System.out.println(operatorsPath);

//Load operators from another file
File operatorFile = new File(operatorsPath);
URL operatorFilePath = operatorFile.toURL();          
URL[] operatorFilePaths = new URL[]{operatorFilePath};
ClassLoader operatorsLoader = new URLClassLoader(operatorFilePaths);
Class operatorInterface = operatorsLoader.loadClass("operators.Operator");
```

The app compiled fine but at runtime I got this exception  :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : operators.Operator

Comment: Compiled class operators.Operator must be on classpath (on runtime, not only compile time). If You run from command line pls read about -cp options

Comment: operators is in d:\operators and my main program is in d:\ProjectFile94.6.7\main  .How can put them in the same class path ?I use command line

Answer (score 0):

You must not append the package name in the classpath directory:

```
String operatorsPath = rootPath.replace("ProjectFile94.6.7" , "").replace("main" , "");
```

i.e. the directory path should be just `D:/`. Otherwise, you're just telling the classloader to search for `D:/operators/operators/Operator.class`.

Comment: I know this but i don't know how to solve it my operators folder is in d:\operators and my main program is in ProjectFile94.6.7\main  .In operatorsPath variable I sould just have d:\operators I don't know how to do this Can yuo help me?

Comment: @marzie I just answered how to solve it. Just don't append the `operators` part at the end so that the classloader looks in the right directory (in this case the directory `D:/`).

Comment: No I should remove this part : replace("ProjectFile94.6.7" , "").replace("main" , "")

Comment: And why are you doing all of this classloading stuff? Can't you just reference the class on the command line? Like `java -cp D:/;D:/ProjectFile94.6.7 main.MainClass`.

Comment: I should load operator(+,*,/,-) from another folder